# getting error with nokogiri gem install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I just installed ruby on my Windows 10 Ubuntu App. I followed procedures here https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm for my ruby installation. I can see that ruby is installed with `ruby -v` command. I then tried doing `gem install rails` and it gives me the following error

https://gofile.io/d/fBv7cm

I am unsure how to rectify this issue. The log was too big to post here so I uploaded it to an external file upload site. Hoping someone can help me out!

Comment: It says permission denied in the last few lines.All the other logs are warnings, which you generally do not need to care about them.

Comment: Honestly I am so frustrated with me having windows. I wish I had a mac at this point. I have reinstalled rvm a number of times according to their guide on single user installation.. yet I still have to run sudo commands on rails application development everytime.. having done this previously on vagrant with no permission denied issues at all this is so frustrating that there is no fix to this issue on WSL

Comment: https://gofile.io/d/fBv7cm -> This upload does not exist